# Effects of oxygenated water on bacteria

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, food-chemistry

I was curious if any of you would happen to have any experience with this but any hypotheses regarding how this would turn out would be much appreciated.

I’m wondering if water fully aerated with oxygen via pressure at a low temp could be useful in food preservation and distribution. For example if soaking meats and seafood in this water could help slow down and prevent bacterial growth.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is just some oxygen dissolved in water. What is different for this oxygen to the one in air? It is not activated or otherwise more reactive.

Comment: We expect questions to show some evidence of prior research: what led you to asking this question? Why would you think oxygen-aerated water could be useful in food preservation?

Comment: Do you want to know about oxygen being toxic at high concentrations? If yes then I guess it could be considering anaerobes cannot survive in oxygenic conditions and high levels of oxygen will also kill aerobes. The practicality, limitations etc are unknown to me.